# What is the standard Cartesian-product construction for Ensemble?

Tags: coq, cartesian-product, set-theory

I am using the `Ensemble` type for sets in `Coq.Sets.Ensemble`. This library defines `Union` and `Intersection` but I cannot find any construction for a Cartesian product.

To be specific, I am looking for a constructor that takes an `Ensemble U` and an `Ensemble V` and returns an `Ensemble (U * V)` that contains the set of all ordered pairs `(u, v)` where `u ∈ U` and `v ∈ V`.

Something explicitly called `Cartesian` would be great. Or maybe there is some way to embed the same idea using normal product types?

I tried to construct a lemma like this:

```
Lemma cartesian_inclusion : forall A B C D : Ensemble U,
    Included U A C /\ Included U B D -> Included (U * U) (A, B) (C, D).
```

But I get the following error:

```
The term "(A, B)" has type "(Ensemble U * Ensemble U)%type" while it is expected to have type "Ensemble (U * U)".
```

This error sort of makes sense. `(A, B)` gives you a product of sets, whereas what I want is a set of products. How can I express this in Coq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `Ensemble U` is simply defined as `U -> Prop`. We can easily define a cartesian product for ensembles as follows:

```
Require Import Coq.Sets.Ensembles.

Definition Cartesian (U V : Type) (A : Ensemble U) (B : Ensemble V) 
  : Ensemble (U * V) :=
  fun x => In _ A (fst x) /\ In _ B (snd x).
```

Here is a proof of the lemma you stated:

```
Lemma cartesian_inclusion U V A B C D :
  Included U A C /\ Included V B D ->
  Included (U * V) (Cartesian _ _ A B) (Cartesian _ _ C D).
Proof.
intros [HU HV] [x y] [HA HB].
split.
- now apply HU.
- now apply HV.
Qed.
```

As an aside, the ensemble library is rarely used in modern Coq developments -- it does not buy you anything over just working with predicates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works perfectly! Your last comment, that "it is usually much easier to simply work over predicates", is intriguing. Do you have a link to an example of that style?

Comment: @MatthewPiziak The `Forall` predicate on lists (in `Coq.Lists.List`), for instance, has type `forall A, (A -> Prop) -> list A -> Prop`, instead of taking an ensemble as its argument. For a more I think I did not express myself clearly in my answer: it is not exactly that working with predicates is _easier_, it's just that ensembles are an unnecessary level of indirection.